# Java: Disruptor: Should Disruptor be used only for POD datatypes?

Tags: disruptor-pattern

Should Disruptor be used only for POD datatypes?

i mean should `Disruptor<T>` be used only for `T` taking values like `byte[], int[], etc` ?

my doubt is that if we use `T` which has `Object` references as its member variables, we need to `new` those member variables, which will lie on heap.
which will again lead to cache misses as the member variable may lie on a totally separate part of heap.

So is my thinking correct that `Disruptor<T>` should be used only for `T` belonging to the set of Plain Old Datatypes (PODs)?

Regards,
VImal

UPDATE: Can someone else please take a look at this question?

UPDATE2:

Reply to @Trisha

Hi Trisha,

Greetings.

i saw the link you mentioned.

`com.lmax.ticketing.api.Message` is inherited from `javolution.io.Struct` and composed of elements from `javolution.io.Struct` and `javolution.io.Union` which makes `Message` to be interoperable between `C/C++`
For any class inheriting from `javolution.io.Struct/Union` the memory layout is defined by the initialization order of the `Struct/Union`'s members and follows the same wordSize rules as `C/C++` structs.

So, in essence, you have control over the memory layout of the elements you put in the `Disruptor`. And all members and sub-members of `Message` are fix sized, i.e. dont have any dynamic memory (`java.lang.Object`)

That is exactly my point also, that we should use such elements whose memory layout we can control and dont have any dynamic memory. And this is done to minimise the cache misses.

Suppose, if a part of the Message was, say, `java.lang.String`, we dont know where JIT compiler would have placed that String. and if i am accessing the `Message.String` in the an `EventHandler` this could have resulted in a cache miss as the String may be present in a totally different chunk of memory..

Am i right?

Comment: I think your question is valid, though maybe phrased wrong. I'm not convinced by the answers yet. If the size of your event object is not fixed, or indeterminate at 'new' time, I don't see how you can keep the garbage collector at bay.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any type of object as an event, for example, see the code at https://github.com/mikeb01/ticketing (e.g. com.lmax.ticketing.web.RequestServlet) - this uses a `Message` as the object in the `RingBuffer`.

The `RingBuffer` is pre-populated with these events using the `EventFactory` provided when you call the `Disruptor` constructor.  So you only create a new instance of them on creation of the `RingBuffer`, and you reuse them throughout the life of your `Disruptor`.  Again, you can see an example of this in the above project.

Comment: Hi Trisha, please see my reply in the Question above. Thanks.

Comment: But if the size of your object is indeterminate (e.g. contains other objects - like a string), how can the system 'allocate' the appropriate space at initialisation?

Answer (score 1):

I would say no, because there's no restriction indicated in the code you wrote.  If the author intended such a thing the code should enforce it.

UPDATE: You've got an answer: "no".  If you get a hundred more "no" answers, will you still need to wait in case a black swan should appear?  Do you have any data to indicate that this is a problem?

Do you assume that all caching solutions would suffer the same fate?  I know of no such restriction on any of the other caching solutions.  Is that more evidence worth considering?

Comment: right, code should restrict it in some way and there is no restriction, but then how about my doubt about cache misses? that is the whole point of using Disruptor so as to minimize the cache misses.

Comment: Maybe your doubt is unfounded.  Perhaps the implementors have accounted for such things inside their implementation.

Comment: i hope it is. But i am really looking for an answer.

Comment: for me, no as an answer is fine. but i also want to know why it doesn't have any impact.

Comment: "...which will lie on heap. which will again lead to cache misses as the member variable may lie on a totally separate part of heap...." - this statement makes no sense to me.  Somebody has to call new sometime.